# Laravel. Как получить размер файла

Tags: php, laravel, filesize

У меня есть вот такой код модели. Мне нужно получить размер файла, возможно ли это сделать с такой моделью на данный момент?

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Program extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'programs';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'catalog',
        'file',
        'sort',
        'visible',
        'model_id',
    ];

    public function getPrograms() {
        return self::query()->where(['visible' => true])->where(['model_id' => $this->id])->orderBy('sort')->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Я пытался добавить вот такой метод  ` public function getFileSize() 
    {
        return Storage::size($this->file_path);
    } `  и вызывать в файле _blade `{{ $item->file->getFileSize() }}` , но получил ошибку `Call to a member function getFileSize() on string (View:`

Comment: Отредактируй вопрос, не надо писать код в комментариях - он тут __нечитаем__

Comment: ибо надо было наверное вызывать `$item->getFileSize()` а не `$item->file->...`

Comment: Да, вы оказались правы надо было написать `$item->getFileSize()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить следующий метод

```
public function getFileSize() 
{
    // Ensure $this->file_path begins with '/public/';
    return Storage::size($this->file);
}
```

А в файле .blade вызвать `$item->getFileSize()`